# how to pass two arguments to function using sys.argv[][python]

Tags: python-2.7

i want to pass two command line arguments.so am giving two arguments to the function .but my code giving me a following error.
importData() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) and am running my script 
"python insert.py 10 20", insert.py is my python file name.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
con = mdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Yogi123$", db="test")
cur = con.cursor()

def importData(count1,count):
    #print count
    for i in range(int(count1),int(count)):
        #print i
        name='jyothi'+str(i)
        #print name
        email='jyothi'+str(i)+'suragani@gmail.com'
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO example (name,email) VALUES ('%s','%s')" %(name,email))
        con.commit()
con.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = importData(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Please post the error and the stack trace in the question above. Is `con.close` correctly indented? And did you mean `con.close()`. You might want to look into context managers and the `with` statement. `sys.argv[2]` is only a single value, if you are trying to pass both `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` then just pass them both in.

Comment: u mean importData(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])